# IDEA creates empty named folders inside JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am creating a JAR file with IntelliJ IDEA and I have noticed that in each folder inside the JAR, there is a subfolder with an empty name. Here is a part of the output of the command jar tf someJar.jar:

```
javax/
javax//
javax/xml/
javax/xml//
javax/xml/parsers/
javax/xml/parsers//
javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class
javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.class
javax/xml/parsers/FactoryConfigurationError.class
javax/xml/parsers/FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError.class
javax/xml/parsers/FactoryFinder.class
javax/xml/parsers/ParserConfigurationException.class
javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.class
javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.class
javax/xml/transform/
javax/xml/transform//
javax/xml/transform/dom/
javax/xml/transform/dom//
javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMLocator.class
```

The JAR is working fine but I'd like to get rid of those folders. Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the output of the command is showing an extra line for each directory (with an extra trailing slash), and that no empty directories are being created.  Un-jar them to verify.

Comment: Well it's not just a line. There is an actual directory with an empty name, I can see it with WinRAR. If I extract the jar those directories don't get extracted though.

Comment: Hmmm so those double slash directories are shown as empty name files in WinRAR?? Do you know if they exist in the directory that IDEA uses to create the jar?  Could remove them by hand then but that's not so good either.  Otherwise report it as a bug to the IDEA folks...

Comment: Actually empty name folders. They do not exist in the project directory. Good idea, I will report this to them!

Comment: Good luck - let me know how it goes; we can update this question once this is resolved.